# Is there an autosave option for vi/nvi

Tags: save, nvi

My version is the following:

```
:ve 
Version nvi-1.81.6nb5 (2009-08-11) The CSRG, University of California, Berkeley.
```

Is it possible to save a file at regular intervals in vi/nvi?

I know there is an "autowrite" option, but that's only when writing to multiple files and switching back an forth.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Use the autosave plugin.
Be aware that it sometimes gets you out of visual mode and problematic in general.
https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-auto-save

Comment: Nvi is not vim. There are no plugins for nvi.